# Get Select2 Id from Multiselect2 from html table row

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-select2

[image]

Hi,
I have a html Table whith multiple rows shows rooms,i want set allocate multiple students to that rooms
with the use of Multi Select2,
The Condition is one student can allocated to any single room so when i have to filter already selected.
student from my search criteria,
please let me know that how can i solve this issue,
Here i have attached screen shot for better understanding of what i want to do exactly 
Here is the code for adding single row.
Thanks,

```
function add_room(data) {

        var room_name = data.name;
        var room_capacity = data.capacity;

        var tr = "<tr id='product_" + i + "'>" +
                "<td>" +
                room_name +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                room_capacity +
                "</td>" +
                "<td align='right'>" +
                "<div class='td_input'>" +
                "<input type='hidden' class='form-control input-sm product student' id='student' placeholder='Select Multiple Students' capacity='" + data.capacity + "' name='room[" + i + "][student]' />" +
                "<input type='hidden' class='form-control input-sm product' id='room_id' value=" + data.id + " name='room[" + i + "][room_id]' />" +
                "</div>" +
                "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
        $("#room_table tbody #add_product_button").before(tr);
        var lastResults = [];

        var elem = $("#product_" + i);
        var capacity = elem.find("#student").attr("capacity");
        elem.find("#student").select2({
            multiple: true,
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            maximumSelectionSize: capacity,
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo site_url("drop_down/get_student"); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                quietMillis: 500,
                data: function(term, page) {
                    return {
                        json: JSON.stringify(lastResults),
                        str: term,
                        status: 0,
                        page_limit: 100,
                        page: page,
                        select2: $("#room_alocation_table_form").serialize()
                    };
                },
                results: function(data, page) {
                    var more = (page * 100) < data.total;
                    lastResults = data.results;
                    return {results: data.results, more: more};
                }
            },
            allowClear: true
        });

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your code as well.

Comment: notice: don't use the same id for few elements, id must be unique.
use suffix for id='student' and id='room_id'

You can add class to select2 element, and gather data by class selector.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer here is my updated function,

```
 function add_product(data) {
            var results = [];
            var bus_name = data.name;
            var bus_seat = data.seat;
            var arr = {};

            if (data.student_id) {
                var ids = data.student_id.split(",");
                var texts = data.student_name.split(",");

                arr = toObject(ids, texts);
                var student_val = arr;
            }
            var tr = "<tr id='product_" + i + "'>" +
                    "<td>" +
                    bus_name +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                    bus_seat +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td align='right'>" +
                    "<div class='td_input'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='form-control input-sm product student' id='student' placeholder='Select Multiple Students' seat='" + data.seat + "' name='bus[" + i + "][student]' />" +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='form-control input-sm' id='bus_id' value=" + data.id + " name='bus[" + i + "][bus_id]' />" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            $("#bus_table tbody #add_product_button").before(tr);
            var lastResults = [];

            var elem = $("#product_" + i);
            var seat = elem.find("#student").attr("seat");

            elem.find("#student").select2({
                multiple: true,
                tokenSeparators: [","],
                maximumSelectionSize: seat,
                ajax: {
                    url: "<?php echo site_url("drop_down/get_student"); ?>",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    quietMillis: 500,
                    data: function(term, page) {
                        return {
                            json: JSON.stringify(lastResults),
                            str: term,
                            status: 0,
                            page_limit: 100,
                            page: page,
                            allocation: "bus",
                        };
                    },
                    results: function(data, page) {
                        var more = (page * 100) < data.total;

                            $.each(data.results, function(i, val) {
                            if ($.inArray(val.id, selected_array) === -1) {
                                results.push({id: val.id, text: val.text});
                            }
                        });
                        var final_data = {results: results, more: more};
                        lastResults = final_data.results;
                        return final_data;
                    }
                },
                allowClear: true
            }).on('change', function() {
                var value = $(this).val().split(",");
                $.grep(value, function(el) {
                    if ($.inArray(el, selected_array) == -1) {
                        selected_array.push(el);
                    }
                });
            });

            if (!$.isEmptyObject(student_val)) {
                elem.find("#student").select2('data', student_val);
            }

            if (!$.isEmptyObject(student_val)) {
                var arr = $.map(student_val, function(el) {
                    selected_array.push(el['id']);
                    return el;
                });
                elem.find("#student").select2('data', arr);
            }

            i++;
        }
```